# Voltage ripple reduction

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator

Is a capacitor or voltage regulator better for reducing voltage ripple in a small 24 VDC power supply coming from a rectified 24 V AC alternator?

Comment: A regulator (which will require additional capacitors) will probably give better ripple rejection than a capacitor alone, but it will also reduce the output voltage.  Which is "better" depends on what you need to accomplish.

Comment: It depends what you need - but please note that a regulator still needs a capacitor in the input or it won't work.

Comment: Hi George, Is it a single-phase or a three-phase alternator? Does it have a permanent magnet rotor or a wound rotor? Is output voltage regulation required? What is the load current? What is the ripple factor that the load can tolerate?

Answer (score 3):

That depends on how much you want to reduce the ripple, how much regulation you want, how much voltage loss you can tolerate, and how much current it's going to need to supply.

A voltage regulator should reduce ripple better than a filter capacitor, but you'll still generally need a filter capacitor before the regulator, it just wouldn't need to be as large as if you were using just a capacitor.

If you're not worried about regulation, another alternative is a capacitance multiplier, this will reduce ripple rather well using a pass transistor and a relatively small value capacitor.

Answer (score 2):

It can be tempting to see a voltage regulator as a perfect device that 'slices' the  top cleanly off a supply waveform.

The image below shows what an ideal voltage regulator could be imagined doing.

But the circuits of real regulators have response characteristics that limit their capabilities. A regulator has to be provided with a supply of a certain quality. And that input quality has a big impact on the quality of the output supply it can provide.

From what you've said, you'll need to use filters to improve the supply rail quality enough for the output quality you need. That's most often parallel smoothing/noise capacitance (sometimes preceded by series inductors themselves preceded by more parallel capacitance for a Pi filter).

You can then consider if the quality is sufficient or requires a voltage regulator. Note that you'll get losses in your regulator which will produce heat, so that needs to be considered too.

[image]